# How can I know which preset was used for an effect in Adobe Audition after the Audition session is saved?

Tags: windows, adobe-audition

How can I know which preset was used for an effect in Adobe Audition after the Audition session is saved?

When I use a preset for an effect, e.g.:

[image]

After the Audition session is saved, when I close Adobe Audition, restart Adobe Audition, reload the preset and look at the effect parameters, I cannot see from which preset it came from:

[image]

I use Adobe Audition CC 2018 Build 11.1.1.3 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed one of Adobe Audition's developers: it is currently (Adobe Audition CC 2019 or earlier) not possible to know which preset was used for an effect in Adobe Audition after the Audition session is saved.

Audition does not save the name of the preset to the session. Reason: The preset can be changed afterwards. Some users would expect that all the references of that are updated automatically, while some others would not want that at all.